# ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m при запуске Scala

Tags: java, jvm, scala

Установил *Play* фрэймворк, и при запуске проекта выдается ошибка:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning:
>   ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0

Как исправить?

> [error]Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.6.4/ivys/ivy.xml

Я так понял, он пытается что-то скачать, но доступа нет из-за этой ошибки?

ОС: Windows 8
Версия Play: play-2.2.6
Версия Java: 1.8.

Нельзя ли по-другому это обойти?

Comment: Насчет первого     Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: 
ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0 - это не ошибка, в этом нет ничего страшного.

Comment: почему Play не может скачать ,xml его таймаутом выкидывает?

Comment: а если ты введешь эту ссылку в браузер, то у тебя скачивание начнется?

Comment: у меня на работе стоит фаэрвол по началу я думал что он блокировал, но когда ввел в браузер то Xml-ка скачалась

Comment: 1. firewall только браузеры пускает или любые программы? 2. Proxy где прописан на браузере или в системе? Если в хроме или IE тогда нормально, если прокси в firefox или Opera тогда из за прокси

Comment: firewall kerio control! в хроме и в IE

Answer (score 3):

Первое - это не ошибка, а предупреждение.

Второе. Установить прокси в браузере недостаточно, его нужно установить на уровне операционной системы.

Вы не указали какую используете ОС и версию Play, поэтому могу предложить воспользоваться общим решением через `activator`. Запустите его так:

> activator -Dhttp.proxyHost="your proxyname" -Dhttp.proxyPort="your port" -Dhttps.proxyHost="your proxyname" -Dhttps.proxyPort="your port"

Дополнительно может потребоваться установить параметры `proxyUser` и `proxyPassword`

**Обновление**

Для Windows 8 и Play 2.2.6 можно решить проблему воспользовавшись этой инструкцией в [документации](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Installing#Add-the-play-script-to-your-PATH), а именно:

> Еслы вы находитесь за прокси, убедитеcь что установлено
>
> для Windows `set HTTP_PROXY=http://<логин>:<пароль>@<хост>:<порт>`

От себя отмечу, что логин и пароль может и не нужен, если прокси его не требует.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете попробовать установить `offline := true` в файле *build.sbt*. Во многих случаях так работает.

Answer (score 1):

Все просто, хоть я и сам потратил какое-то время на решение этой задачи:
1-перейти в каталог cd opt/glassfish4/bin/
2-запустить с ROOT правами sudo ./asadmin start-domain
3-остановка сервера тоже с ROOT правами sudo ./asadmin stop-domain
В вашем случае все должно заработать.